# how i can run some part of a program in cpu and some parts in gpu?

Tags: visual-c++, opencl

I want to write a program that some of the codes run in cpu and some of that in run in gpu.  i want to use opencl.it is possible to do it if yes how i can do that?an i want to use visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using [AMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is supported by microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple devices in OpenCL. Use the given APIs to get info on devices and then use the handle to create context on each device. Rest is as easy as a simple OpenCL program. You can also launch a task-parallel kernel. More info is available in AMD/nVIDIA OpenCL Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that, That's how large programs make of CPU+ GPU combination. If you think part of your code can be parallelized such as unrolling few loops or if you are working disconnected data sets then put those items on GPU. If it is sequential and requires lot of synchronization and does busy wait on some of the loops then put it in CPU.

The way to accomplish this is simple, first write your algorithm/logic in the host part, then using OpenCL API functions setup the GPU for executing parallel code, The functions run on GPU compute unit is called as kernel, so you need to write a kernel function in OpenCL (C99)languague.

There are good pointers in the web which can help you accomplish this.

1. AMD APP SDK 2.7
   http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx
   you will lots of OpenCL Samples ranging from simple hello world to complex algorithms implemented in a easy way.
2. AMD APP Profiler
   This comes along with AMD APP SDK 2.7 and helps you profile what you have written
3. AMD gDEBugger http://developer.amd.com/tools/gDEBugger/Pages/default.aspx

This helps you in debugging OpenCL programs in GPU, for host code debugging use Visual Studio debugger.

Intel also provides similar samples look here:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-samples/

Nvidia Samples are here:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/sdk/website/OpenCL/website/samples.html